# Split pdf a4 to a5 with a command line tool

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm looking for a free command line tool able to Split a A4 pdf document info a A5 pdf file.

I have already looked at http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/ But it lacks documentation, so I haven't been able to use it.

My A4 document consist of multiple pages where one side is always empty.
[image: Original A4 PDF] 
I want to end up with a result like this.
[image]

A commandline tool would be preferred, but a solution in C# would also be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an example, with itextsharp it does not fit the A4 to the best in the A5
it just import a page of A4 and put it in A5..

Just set the margins and you will get the output you want....

I'm using [itextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

```
var _readerGlobal = new PdfReader(@"c:\temp\bicicleta.pdf");
MemoryStream _thePdfFile = new MemoryStream();

var _documentGlobal = new Document(PageSize.A5, 50, 50, 50, 50);

var _writerGlobal = PdfWriter.GetInstance(_documentGlobal, _thePdfFile);
_writerGlobal.SetFullCompression();

_documentGlobal.Open();

var _cbGlobal = _writerGlobal.DirectContent;
PdfImportedPage page1 = _writerGlobal.GetImportedPage(_readerGlobal, 1);
_cbGlobal.AddTemplate(page1, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);

_documentGlobal.CloseDocument();

var _pdfBytes = _thePdfFile.ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp\bicicletaA5.pdf", _pdfBytes);
```